# Avoid naming container / region on nested composite component children with include

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm having problems rerendering the relevant parts of my view without having to resort to `@form` or the like.

I have a composite component like this:

`wrapper.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <cc:interface componentType="compositeComponent">
        <cc:attribute required="false" name="foo" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
      <a4j:region>        
        <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block" styleClass="my-wrapper">

            <h1>TITLE</h1>

            <c:forEach items="#{element.children}" var="element">
                <ui:include src="element.xhtml">
                   <ui:param name="level" value="0" />
                </ui:include>
            </c:forEach>

        </h:panelGroup>
      </a4j:region>      

    </cc:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

and `element.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

         <h:outputLabel styleClass="level-#{level}">
             #{element.label}
             <a4j:ajax event="click"
                listener="#{controller.updateElements(element)}"
                execute="@this" render="@region" />
        </h:outputLabel>        

        <c:if test="#{element.someTest}">
            <c:forEach items="#{element.children}" var="element">
                <ui:include src="element.xhtml">
                   <ui:param name="level" value="#{level + 1}" />
                </ui:include>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>

</ui:composition>
```

Now the problem is, although I'm setting an `<a4j:region>` around the wrapper, and setting the render expression in the children to `@region`, it still only renders the single clicked upon child on rerender.

I searched the web and SO but couldn't find a reason for this, does the include implicitly create a namespace or naming container (which would be treated as a region?)? Couldn't find anything like this, but if so, how would I avoid this? I want the entire wrapper (and only that, not `@form` or `@all` or the like) to be rerendered upon clicking on a child.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`@region` is only used for execution. The `<a4j:region>` doesn't generate any HTML so you cannot use it for rendering.

Comment: oh ok. but how would I restrict the rendering to certain areas?

Comment: You mean by ID? Because I want to create a generic component that can be used inside different panelGroups or whatever. I just want to define some region outside. Or is there a way to say "up until the next panelGroup"?

Comment: You could pass the id-to-render as a parameter if you want to do it that way.